# using std::cout in multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, stdthread

I write a simple program for testing Thread in c++11 but `std::cout` doesnt work as I expect.

```
class Printer
{
public:
    void exec()
    {
        mutex m;
        m.lock();
        cout<<"Hello  "<<this_thread::get_id()<<endl;
        chrono::milliseconds duration( 100 );
        this_thread::sleep_for( duration );
        m.unlock();

    }
};

int main()
{
    Printer printer;

    thread firstThread([&printer](){
        while(1)
            printer.exec();

    });
    thread secondThread([&printer](){
        while(1)
            printer.exec();
    });

    firstThread.join();
    secondThread.join();     
}
```

some of the results :

```
Hello 11376
Hello 16076
Hello 16076
Hello Hello 11376
16076
Hello 11376
,....
```

I used mutex for locking threads so I cant understand why two threads are executing `std::cout` at the same time. 
It seams very weired to me.Can any one explain what is happening!?!

Comment: Once you implement the solution provided in the answer you should also move to using `lock_guard`s rather than manual lock/unlock calls. And don't bother flushing (e.g., with `endl`); just use '\n'.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The threads are using *different* `mutex` instances as the `mutex` is a local variable in the `exec()` function so locking the `mutex` is pointless as each thread will be locking its own `mutex` resulting in no synchronization between the threads. The same `mutex` instance must be used by the threads to achieve synchronization.

To correct in the posted code, make the `mutex` a member variable. However, if another `Printer` object was created then there would be no synchronization between threads that used different `Printer` instances. In this case, the `mutex` would need to be a `static` member variable to ensure synchronization:

```
class Printer
{
public:
    //...
private:
    static std::mutex mtx_;
};

std::mutex Printer::mtx_;
```

---

To ensure a `mutex` is always released, regardless if a function exits normally or via an exception, use [`std:lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard):

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m); // 'm' locked, and will be
                                     // unlocked when 'lock' is destroyed.
std::cout<< "Hello  " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
std::chrono::milliseconds duration( 100 );
std::this_thread::sleep_for( duration );
```

Comment: Fix is to declare `mutex` with `static` storage duration. ... or that.

Comment: @Casey, or a member variable as the threads are using the same `Printer` instance.

Comment: @hjmd I would prefer `static` in this case to correspond to the scope of `std::cout`. That way it will keep working when some maintenance programmer down the line creates another `Printer` in some other function.

Comment: unique_lock would be better in this case, because allows unlock-ing just after sending data to cout and before entering sleep (there is no good in holding the mutex during the sleep).

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer is correct.  However it is nice to separate concerns:

1. You need a way to print to `std::cout` in a thread safe manner.
2. You need to create objects/functors/functions to run in threads and launch them.

Here is a utility I use that just concentrates on collecting arguments to `std::cout` and streaming them out under a `static std::mutex`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

std::ostream&
print_one(std::ostream& os)
{
    return os;
}

template <class A0, class ...Args>
std::ostream&
print_one(std::ostream& os, const A0& a0, const Args& ...args)
{
    os << a0;
    return print_one(os, args...);
}

template <class ...Args>
std::ostream&
print(std::ostream& os, const Args& ...args)
{
    return print_one(os, args...);
}

std::mutex&
get_cout_mutex()
{
    static std::mutex m;
    return m;
}

template <class ...Args>
std::ostream&
print(const Args& ...args)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(get_cout_mutex());
    return print(std::cout, args...);
}
```

This code can be reused for streams other than `std::cout`, but the above is specialized to just target `std::cout`.  With this your `Printer::exec()` can now be significantly simplified:

```
void exec()
{
    print("Hello ", std::this_thread::get_id(), '\n');
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```

Now, not only will your `Printer` use `cout` in a threadsafe manner, and has been simplified (e.g. doesn't need to maintain its own `mutex` for `cout`), but all of your other types and functions can also use `cout` and all interoperate together safely.  The `print` function itself now maintains the `mutex`, and that fact is encapsulated away from all of `print`'s clients.

Comment: print is a template function. I think you could end up with more than one mutex.

Comment: @JanChristophUhde: Excellent observation!  And it only took 3 years for someone to notice! :-)  Fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sharing the trick from Nicolás given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196155/is-there-anyway-to-write-the-following-as-a-c-macro) that I find to be more elegant than Howard Hinnant implementation. The idea is to create a temporary ostringstream object and put the protection code on the destructor.

```
/** Thread safe cout class
  * Exemple of use:
  *    PrintThread{} << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
  */
class PrintThread: public std::ostringstream
{
public:
    PrintThread() = default;

    ~PrintThread()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_mutexPrint);
        std::cout << this->str();
    }

private:
    static std::mutex _mutexPrint;
};

std::mutex PrintThread::_mutexPrint{};
```

You can then use it as a regular `std::cout`, from any thread:

```
PrintThread{} << "val = " << 33 << std::endl;
```

The object collect data as a regular `std::ostringstream`. As soon the coma is reached, the object is destroyed and flush all collected information.

Comment: Here is a slight [refinement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288135/2074605) of this answer with a test case.

Comment: In your example usage of PrintThread, the `std::endl' manipulator could (should?) be replaced by '\n' since you're writing to an ostringstream-dervied object.  Note that when the ~PrintThread() destructor is invoked the "this" object is flushed when the base class std::ostringstream destructor is called, so there's no need to "manually" flush the PrintThread object via std::endl. And in your ~PrintThread() destructor method it might be worthwhile to flush the cout stream after writing "this->str()" to cout--i.e., std::cout << this->str() << std::flush;.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider a global `std::mutex cout_mutex;` (somewhere in your namespaces), which is used to protected `std::cout` output. Make sure you use `std::lock<std::mutex>` (so you cannot forget to unlock the mutex and for exception safety).