# Why is my program printing garbage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void function_1()
{
    std::cout << "Thread t1 started!\n";
    for (int j=0; j>-100; j--) {
        std::cout << "t1 says: " << j << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(function_1); // t1 starts running

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        std::cout << "from main: " << i << "\n";
    }

    t1.join(); // main thread waits for t1 to finish
    return 0;
}
```

I create a `thread` that prints numbers in decreasing order while `main` prints in increasing order.

Sample output [here](https://gist.github.com/sivapvarma/0dd6ca186a93e8f30ae7#file-output-txt). Why is my code printing garbage ?

Comment: I am not sure why you can't access it. It is a public gist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both threads are outputting at the same time, thereby scrambling your output.
You need some kind of thread synchronization mechanism on the printing part.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18277334/5708620) for an example using a [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) combined with [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) for `cout`.

Answer (score 9):

It's not "garbage" — it's the output you asked for! It's just jumbled up, because you have used a grand total of *zero* synchronisation mechanisms to prevent individual `std::cout << ... << std::endl` lines (which are not atomic) from being interrupted by similar lines (which are still not atomic) in the other thread.

Traditionally we'd lock a *mutex* around each of those lines.