# The uses of std::osyncstream?

Tags: c++, c++20

What are the uses of the new C++20 `std::osyncstream` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream)? Isn't the `std::ostream` already thread-safe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [How to easily make std::cout thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718124/how-to-easily-make-stdcout-thread-safe)

it looks like it is not thread-safe. They even (the first answer in that question) suggest to make a wrapper, which is basically what `std::osyncstream` offers.

Answer (score 2):

Writing to a log file or to `std::cout` from different threads, atomically.
That's the first thing I thought of.

In such a scenario, written data won't be interleaved or garbled.