# Is std::cout thread safe for single output

Tags: c++

Suppose there are several threads, each thread invokes

```cpp
std::cout << 123;
```

for each statement, it should output 3 characters, '1', '2', and '3'. So does the C++ standard guarantees that the '1' '2' and '3' will not interleave? i.e., the system will not output the following result:
112233

Thanks

Comment: std::cout is threadsafe in the sense that it will not crash, but output can become mixed.

Comment: FYI: [How to easily make std::cout thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26909227/7478597)