# How to call operator<< on "this" in a descendant of std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

```
class mystream : public std::stringstream
{
public:
    void write_something()
    {
        this << "something";
    }
};
```

This results in the following two compile errors on VC++10:

```
error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char [10]'
error C2296: '<<' : illegal, left operand has type 'mystream *const '
```

<strike>Judging from the second one, this is because what `this` points at can't be changed, but the << operator does (or at least is declared as if it does). Correct?</strike>

Is there some other way I can still use the `<<` and `>>` operators on `this`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mystream *const` means that `this` is a constant pointer to a non-constant object. The problem is that you're trying to stream-insert into a pointer -- you must insert into a stream. Try the following.

```
*this << "something";
```

Answer (score 1):

The destructor of an stringstream (actually a `basic_stringstream<char>` ) is not virtual, and as all classes from the C++ SL, you're not really supposed to derive from them...

Depending on what exactly you want to do, I will tell you to prefer composition to inheritance, and maybe create your own templated << and >> operators that will use your underlying stream. Or maybe it is wiser not to use a stringstream as a member.

Comment: I got my inspiration from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196155/is-there-anyway-to-write-the-following-as-a-c-macro which has enough votes for me to perceive such derivation as acceptable. I've also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922248/is-there-any-real-risk-to-deriving-from-the-c-stl-containers following your advice though.

Comment: Because this clever trick does not really work and you can have some problems?? :)  try `my_macro << std::string("surprise")`

Comment: Nikko is right about my_macro.  It creates an anonymous instance of my_stream, this instance will only work for operator << methods, and not for operator << functions.  The code will compile but you can produce different output on different platforms.

Comment: Regarding the destructor not being virtual.  This would only be a problem if you or anyone else tried to destroy my_stream virtaly.  That is 

   std::stringstream * stream = new mystream;
   (*stream) << "stuff";
   delete stream;

This would not work, and there is now way you can prevent this type of code being written.  However documenting that my_stream should never be deleted polymorphically would prevent this then you code would be safe, except for the fact that global functions will not work with the macro.

Comment: It is safer to use delegation for this, see my answer to a similar question that gets round the `my_macro << std::string("surprise")` problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328568/custom-stream-manipulator-for-class/1329092#1329092

Comment: @iain It does not compile with gcc 4.3